# Unable to get insert, update and delete to work with spring-data-jpa

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, crud

I am trying to create a web service that performs basic CRUD operations written using spring boot 2. The select operation works fine, however the insert, delete and update operations have no effect as their query is not getting generated and executed.

I have looked through different examples but I am unable to figure out any issues. The major concern for me is the fact that not even a query is being triggered for insert, delete or update operations.

Student Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Student {

@Id
@NotNull
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "course")
private String course;

public Student(int id, String name, String course) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.course = course;
}

public Student(){}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getCourse() {
    return course;
}

public void setCourse(String course) {
    this.course = course;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Student{ id=" + id + ", name='" + name + '\'' + ", course='" + course + '\'' + '}';
}
}
```

StudentDaoImpl

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class StudentDaoImpl implements StudentDao {

@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

@Override
public List<Student> fetchAllStudents() {
    Session session = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).openSession();
    CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Student> cq = cb.createQuery(Student.class);
    Root<Student> root = cq.from(Student.class);
    CriteriaQuery<Student> all = cq.select(root);
    List<Student> solution = session.createQuery(all).getResultList();
    session.close();
    return solution;
}

@Override
public Student deleteStudent(Integer id) {
    Session session = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).openSession();
    Student student = session.load(Student.class, id);
    if (student != null){
        session.delete(student);
        session.close();
    }
    return student;
}

@Override
public Student fetchForId(Integer id){
    Session session = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).openSession();
    Student student = session.load(Student.class, id);
    session.close();
    return student;
}

@Override
public Student insertStudent(Student student) {
    Session session = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).openSession();
    session.save(student);
    session.close();
    return student;
}

@Override
public Student updateStudent(Student student) {
    Session session = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).openSession();
    Student studentCheck = session.load(Student.class, student.getId());
    if (studentCheck != null) {
        session.saveOrUpdate(student);
        session.close();
    }
    return student;
}
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.database = MYSQL
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

## Edit

Replacing EntityManagerFactory with EntityManager( + Persistent Context Annotation) worked for me. However I still haven't figured why persistence worked for EntityManager.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not strictly important, you can do it using `NativeQuery` and its `executeUpdate` API:

```
String query = "insert into student values(1,?)";

em.createNativeQuery(query)
   .setParameter(1, "Tom")
   .executeUpdate();
```

Comment: After switching to EntityManager, the issue was resolved. However I am not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest this repository

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Integer> {

}
```

Probably you have to change the id of Student from int to Integer.

And this repository has the methods for retrieving, updating, creating and deleting.

Let's say that you want to use this repository in a Service, you can do that like this:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public class StudentService {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    ......

}
```

Comment: I wanted to implement my own Repository rather than using the inbuilt one. However, this also works but its not what I wanted.